# System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure, sharepoint

I want to develop a Sharepoint webhook using C# (.Net Framework v 4.5) and ASP.Net. For this I take the following packages:

```
<packages>
  <package id="Antlr" version="3.5.0.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="AppForSharePointOnlineWebToolkit" version="3.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="AppForSharePointWebToolkit" version="3.1.5" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="bootstrap" version="3.4.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="3.4.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.7" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.de" version="5.2.7" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.7" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.de" version="3.2.7" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.de" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.7" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.7" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client.de" version="5.2.7" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.7" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core.de" version="5.2.7" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage" version="5.2.7" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Tracing" version="5.2.7" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.7" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost.de" version="5.2.7" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.7" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.de" version="3.2.7" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Edm" version="5.8.4" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.OData" version="5.8.4" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Services.Client" version="5.8.4" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens" version="6.12.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging" version="6.12.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocol.Extensions" version="1.0.4.403061554" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols" version="5.5.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WsFederation" version="5.5.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" version="6.12.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml" version="5.5.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Xml" version="5.5.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="4.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.de" version="4.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.de" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="4.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.ActiveDirectory" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.ActiveDirectory.de" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.de" version="4.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt" version="4.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt.de" version="4.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" version="4.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM" version="16.1.5521.1200" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Modernizr" version="2.8.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="10.0.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="SharePointPnPCoreOnline" version="2.6.1608.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" version="6.12.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="System.Spatial" version="5.8.4" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.6.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WindowsAzure.Storage" version="9.3.3" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

But I get after the first start in the following class this message:
Compiler Error CS0246 and CS7069 in TokenValidationParameters

> Error CS7069 The reference to type "TokenValidationParameters" was supposedly declared in "System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" but could not be found.

and

> Error CS0246 The type or namespace name "TokenValidationParameters" was not found (possibly missing a using directive or assembly reference).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IdentityModel;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel;
using System.Linq; 
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.ActiveDirectory;
using Owin;

namespace WebApplication
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
                new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"],
                    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters {
                         ValidAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"]
                    },
                });
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

I don't have so much experience in C# and ASP.NET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason for **Error CS0246** The type or namespace name **"TokenValidationParameters"** was not found (possibly missing a using directive or assembly reference) is
**Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens** Assembly  reference  is missing in the .cs file.
Please import the below namespace in class file.

```
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my very similar case (using a .NET 6.0 project), I had, "error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Jwt' does not exist in the namespace 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens' (are you missing an assembly reference?)".

I resolved it by adding "using **System**.IdentityModel.Tokens;" to the affected *.cs source file. Notice that I used the System namespace, not Microsoft. Also notice that I did not include the type or namespace Jwt anymore.

In fact, your line where it says, "using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;" was what yielded the CS0234 error for me. Removing the ".Jwt" is what fixed my problem.